# AWS EC2 - Enforcing Private IP to be used for external DNS lookup for internal communication?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 server running a web application that is using the DNS created and owned by a third party, which isn't on my domain. My application needs to perform internal communication via the DNS name, and I need the DNS to resolve to the Private IP address not the Public address. How can I do this in AWS? Currently it keeps using the Public address and failing to resolve.

Comment: Is tweaking your `hosts` file on the instance an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three options.

1. Switch to Route 53. Route 53 supports split horizon DNS via public / private zones. This integrates well with AWS VPCs.
2. Install your own DNS server to resolve private addresses within your VPC and forward other queries to the third party DNS server.
3. Create a custom hosts file (/etc/hosts) and replicate to each of your instances.

The easiest method is to use a custom hosts file since you probably cannot use Route 53 due to the third party. Since you only mention one EC2 instance, go with the /etc/hosts option.

Comment: Thanks for the three detailed suggestions John, we went with option 2 as we have multiple instances.